# Ruby (Sinatra) JSON.parse do not work with json data

Tags: ruby, json, knockout.js, sinatra

I'm geting  json object from knockout.js with ko.toJSON

```
self.cmaterials = ko.observableArray([]);
```

....

```
    ko.computed(function() {
    $.ajax({
         url: "/editcmat1",
         type: "PUT",
         data: ko.toJSON(
            self.cmaterials
         )
     });
});
```

Ruby code

```
puts params
```

> {"id":34,"name":"Concrete","material_id":3}

when I try to convert it

```
puts JSON.parse(js)
```

> TypeError - can't convert Hash into String:

how can I make it a usable Ruby hash.

```
puts parse.keys
  {"id":34,"name":"Concrete","material_id":3}
```

Comment: I dont quite get the question, `params` is already a `Hash`

Comment: If you do `params.class` what do you get?

Comment: yes ruby indicates as a hash, but `params.keys` returns whole params, as it is a key.

Comment: Could you update the question with the code that makes the transformation to `json`, I mean the `javascript` with `ko.toJSON(this)` call.

Answer (score 0):

To do what you were trying to do with your code, you would do:

```
 puts JSON.parse(js).to_s
```

Using the `JSON.parse` method makes it a usable hash. You are trying to output that hash using `puts` which would mean you have to convert it to a string. If you want to access that hash, just do:

```
hash = JSON.parse(js)
puts hash["id"] #34
puts hash["name"] #concrete
etc...
```